# how to avoid chcp when starting python from cmd

Tags: python-2.7, cmd

I am a little tired of having to input first `chcp 936` before using python with command line. (more details: my python version is `2.7`, and os is `Windows 8` and I am starting command line under the File menu of my project folder. )

`936` represents coding for Simplified `Chinese GBK`; Python 2.7 seems to be unaware of code page `65001` (meaning `utf-8`) which is the default setting for my command line, and thus causes error whenever it runs a program.

So I wonder if it is possible to configure the cmd setting so that it uses code page `936` as the default setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shortcut pointing to `cmd /k "chcp 936"`

EDITED - With the same idea, but to integrate into shell, save as `.reg` file and run

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;--------------------------------------------
; Create handler for right click on directory
;--------------------------------------------

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmdPython]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmdPython]
@="Open python command window here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmdPython\command]
@="cmd /k pushd \"%L\" & chcp 936"

;-------------------------------------------------------
; Create handler for right click on directory background
;-------------------------------------------------------

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmdPython]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmdPython]
@="Open python command window here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmdPython\command]
@="cmd /k pushd \"%L\" & chcp 936"

;----------------------------------------
; Create handler for right click on drive
;----------------------------------------

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmdPython]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmdPython]
@="Open python command window here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\cmdPython\command]
@="cmd /k pushd \"%L\" & chcp 936"
```

Comment: I know what you mean, thanks. But I wish to start python with cmd from the folders that I am working on so that I wouldn't have to cd to each folder each time.

Comment: @Peihui: see updated answer. Hope this will do what you need.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i was looking for. I tried this reg today. Unfortunately, the section for directory background does not work. Seems the cmd parameter needs some polishing.

Answer (score 2):

Create a batch file called `c.bat` and put it on the path:  You can type c and press enter.

Additionally you can put the python command inside the batch file to accept parameters, if that fits in with your tasks.

```
@echo off
chcp 936
```

Alternately there is an `autoexec.nt` in the `system32` folder which launches with `cmd` and you can add commands there.

Comment: The problem with using autoexec.nt can be just the oposite. All command windows open with pagecode 936.

Comment: @foxidrive: are you sure that autoexec.nt is there. In my windows 8, there is no such file.

Comment: @Peihui Yes, it's in the system32 folder in my Windows 8.1 too.